# Pass values among build scripts in apache Ant

Tags: ant

I am looking for help as I am unable to pass values among ant script. 
The job of my ant script is to compile the source code and later zip all the files into one folder and name it such as - compile-2.0.0.0.zip.

I have been reading the number "2.0.0.0" from a properties file. My ant script structure looks like this..

#### Base directory "A":

#### build-common.xml

--> reads the property file and assign value in one variable. code looks like this -

```
<propertyfile file="./build.properties" >
   <entry key="VERSION_NUMBER" type="string" default="2.0.0.0"/>                    
</propertyfile>
```

Same Base directory "A": buildA.xml

> message="******* GENERATING EXE  S{VERSION_NUMBER}************************" />

Directory "B": (buildB.xml called by buildA.xml)

> message="******* GENERATING EXE  S{VERSION_NUMBER}************************" />

The problem is - I cannot access ${VERSION_NUMBER} in buildB.xml. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Code to call buildB.xml from buildA.xml..

```
 <antcall target="antCall" >        
    <param name="antDir" value="${pathB}"/>         
</antcall>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: is this a typo? the outpur says: S{VERSION_NUMBER} but it should be ${VERSION_NUMBER}. Did you confuse S with $ here?

Comment: @oers, obviously. @user381878, in the `antcall`, you can pass `VERSION_NUMBER` as another param.

Comment: @khachik yeah that's what i thought first too, BUT antcall doesn't call another buildfile it just calls a target in the same buildfile. The ant target would do the job. But both tasks inherit properties automatically. You don't need to specify them.

Comment: Hi Everyone...the problem is solved. I have figured it out by myself..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That how the value gets passed to another ant script in different directory !

```
 <antcall target="antCall" >        
    <param name="antDir" value="${pathB}"/>
     <param name="VERSION_NUMBER" value="${VERSION_NUMBER}" />    
</antcall>
```